# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion

This question was still not asked, and I think we need to start this discussion:

I know the entire period is actually to define these issues, but let this be the central place, where we can consolidate the points we do decide on.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/ define that we need this, and from reading questions both on [Meta](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/) and [main](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/) and from other site, Mainly [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) I think we should build our FAQ

SuperUser's looks like this

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer
> - networking
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles websites or web services like Facebook,
>     Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks a shopping or
>     buying recommendation …
>
> then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s
>   also OK to ask and answer your own question.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my first attempt at writing the FAQ. Please note that I've marked this answer as "Community Wiki", so feel free to edit it to add, remove, and improve and answer.

---

### What kind of question can I ask here?

Salesforce StackExchange is for Salesforce.com and Force.com users, admins, and developers. It is run by the Salesforce community, for the Salesforce community and, while Salesforce.com employees participate, it is not governed by Salesforce.com in any way. If you have a question about...

- Salesforce.com CRM application
- Force.com platform
- AppExchange app development
- Mobile app development using Force.com SDK
- Integration with any of the above using one of the [Integration options](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Integration)

and it is not about...

- Mobile App Development in general
- Cloud Computing (Saas, PaaS) in general
- Soliciting help to write test suites for your code
- Soliciting help to write actual code for your given requirement

...then you've found the right place to ask your question.

### What kind of question should I not ask here?

You should only ask **practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face**. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

(The above section was adapted from [MetaFilter’s FAQ](http://faq.metafilter.com/tags/chatfilter). For more detail, see [six guidelines for great subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).)

If your question is about the site itself, please don't ask it here. Visit our [meta-discussion site](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/) where you can talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags should be used, suggest a feature, point out a bug, or generally discuss how Salesforce SE works.

If your question would be of interest to …

Professional and enthusiast programmers, ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).
System administrators and desktop support professionals, ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).
Power users of web applications, ask on [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com).
Enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system, ask on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com).

Perhaps your question would be a better fit on another Stack Exchange site; see the [site directory](http://stackexchange.com/sites) for details.

### What is SFSE?

(**S**)ales(**F**)orce (**S**)tack(**E**)xchange

---

I think everything else can be copied verbatim from the Super User FAQ, since it is applicable to this site as well. The important bit is the first part - what kind of question can I ask here that needs more attention and thought?

Anup

Comment: Definitely need a mention of the fact that Salesforce StackExchange is run by the Salesforce community, for the Salesforce community and, while salesforce.com employees participate, it is not governed by salesforce.com in any way.

Comment: agreed. It can be under the "What kind of question can I ask here?" section. Something along the lines of "Salesforce SE is for Salesforce.com and Force.com users, administrators, and developers. SF SE is curated and run by the Salesforce community for Salesforce devs, admins and users, and while salesforce.com employees participate, it is not governed by Salesforce.com."

Comment: (1) We need to explicitly mention something about what constitutes an appropriate question/answer about the AppExchange to prevent promotional efforts (http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/95/are-questions-about-apps-in-the-app-exchange-off-topic AND http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88/is-this-question-a-good-candidate-to-downvote).  (2) We need to have something explicit that states that questions about Salesforce related technologies (e.g., Heroku) are only appropriate if they deal with SF integration (http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/54/154)

Comment: @PeterKnolle, This is a community wiki, so feel free to add your edits directly to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I was hoping that the community would contribute to this wiki post, but not much here to see so far. Come on people! Contribute, UpVote etc!