# Is there a way to make a letter in a word bold?

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

I think this is likely a common problem across the network unless I'm doing things wrong... I do remember a Jeff Atwood blog post discussing the regexes used for the editor but it seems to be that you can't make a single letter in a word **bold** if you want to.

[I was trying to write "SalesForce StackExchange"](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90/what-should-our-faq-contain) with the capitals in bold, but it seems you end up with single asterisks surrounding the letter in question, for example:

ThereShouldBeABold**B**InthisMashedUpWord

However, as you can see the *italic* kicks in instead, leaving the other two asterisks pointing. Is this regarded as a bug, or was it a nice way of handling double pointers in C/C++? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can - but you have to resort to [using HTML directly](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#html):

```
<b>S</b>ales<b>F</b>orce <b>S</b>tack <b>E</b>xchange <br>
ThereShouldBeABold<b>B</b>InThisMashedUpWord
```

> **S**ales**F**orce **S**tack **E**xchange 
> ThereShouldBeABold**B**InThisMashedUpWord

These also work inline.

And yeah, relaxing the interpretation of these (and underscores) tends to do all manner of horrible things to code.

Comment: Heh, how did I never notice that you could use HTML tags. -10 points to me!